# Как сгруппировать объекты ObjectManager в GeoObjectCollection?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Как в яндекс мап сгруппировать объекты, добавленные в ObjectManager в GeoObjectCollection для того, чтобы управлять их свойствами? 
Есть набор различных объектов (geoObjects), которые на карте должны быть выделены разными цветами (в частности fillColor и strokeColor). 
Сами эти свойства не хранятся в базе и должны назначаться после добавления их на карту.
Объекты добавляются в objectManager через запрос:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/.../object/objects-json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
        objectManager.add(data);
        }
    });
```

и на сколько я понял из описания [objectManager](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/ObjectManager-docpage/), в нем нет возможности группировать объекты по коллекциям [GeoObjectCollection](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/GeoObjectCollection-docpage/), а значит и нет возможности задавать свойства отдельным группам объектов. Так ли это?
Например код:

```
objectManager.objects.options.set("fillColor", "fff000");
```

меняет свойство всех объектов objectManager

Вопрос: как сделать возможным изменение свойств разных групп объектов в objectManager? Если это не возможно, то какие варианты есть?

Пример содержимого data:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 0, "geometry": {"type": "Circle", "coordinates": [...], "radius": 1}, "properties": {"hintContent": "Текст"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 1, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [...]}, "properties": {"hintContent": "Текст"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 2, "geometry": {"type": "Polyline", "coordinates": [...]}, "properties": {"hintContent": "Текст"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 3, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [...]}, "properties": {"hintContent": "Текст"}}
    ]
}
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Что именно не получилось? Объясните более техническим языком (неплохо будет если покажете код, от которого вы ожидали решения вашей проблемы и напишете чем его результат отличается от ожидаемого)

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример с созданием двух коллекций, заданием параметров объектов внутри коллекций и изменением параметра уже после добавления объектов (это может быть сделано, например, по какому-либо событию)

```js
ymaps.ready(function() {
 var map = new ymaps.Map("map", {
            center: [55.76, 37.64], 
            zoom: 7
        });
    // Cоздаем две коллекции
    var redObjects = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection({}, {
        preset: "islands#redCircleIcon"
    });
    var blueObjects = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection({}, {
        preset: "islands#blueCircleIcon"
    });
    // Добавляем их на карту
    map.geoObjects.add(redObjects);
    map.geoObjects.add(blueObjects);
    // Добавляем в коллекции метки
    redObjects.add(new ymaps.Placemark([55.8, 37.5]));
    redObjects.add(new ymaps.Placemark([55.9, 37.7]));
    blueObjects.add(new ymaps.Placemark([55.4, 37.3]));
    blueObjects.add(new ymaps.Placemark([55.7, 37.6]));
    blueObjects.add(new ymaps.Placemark([55.5, 37.8]));
    // Меняем вид иконок
    blueObjects.options.set("preset", "islands#blueIcon");
});
```

```html
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru-RU"></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 280px"></div>
```

**Дополнено**:

Если принципиально добавлять через `ObjectManager`, то на результат это повлияет мало. Все равно в `geoObjects` будет список объектов типа [GeoObject](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/GeoObject-docpage/). Но можно организовать этап парсинга ваших данных при помощи API. Для этого результат запроса следует преобразовать в [GeoQueryResult](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/GeoQueryResult-docpage/) и к результату уже можно применять параметры (цвет, толщина ...). Причем его также можно менять для получившейся "коллекции" целиком. Вот пример:

```js
ymaps.ready(function() {
 var map = new ymaps.Map("map", {
   center: [55.76, 37.64], 
   zoom: 7
  });
 var data1 = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
   {"type": "Feature", "id": 1, "geometry": {"type": "Circle", "coordinates": [56.2, 37.3], "radius": 50000}, "properties": {"hintContent": "Текст"}},
   {"type": "Feature", "id": 1, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[56.2, 37.2], [55.3, 37.7], [56.1, 37.9]]]}, "properties": {"hintContent": "Текст"}},
   {"type": "Feature", "id": 2, "geometry": {"type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[55.7, 37.1], [55.2, 37.6], [56.1, 38.4]]}, "properties": {"hintContent": "Текст"}}
  ]
 };
 var data2 = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
   {"type": "Feature", "id": 1, "geometry": {"type": "Circle", "coordinates": [56.9, 37.3], "radius": 50000}, "properties": {"hintContent": "Текст"}}
  ]
 };
 var gq1 = ymaps.geoQuery(data1);
 var gq2 = ymaps.geoQuery(data2);
 gq1.setOptions({
  strokeColor: '#f00',
  strokeWidth: 4,
  fillColor: '#00ff0040'
 });
 gq2.setOptions({
  strokeColor: '#0f0',
  strokeWidth: 2,
  fillColor: '#0000ff40'
 });
 gq1.addToMap(map);
 gq2.addToMap(map);
 $('#blue').on('click', function() {
  gq1.setOptions({
   strokeColor: '#00f'
  });
 })
});
```

```html
<button id="blue">Сделать синим</button>
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px"></div>
<script src="https://yastatic.net/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
```

Кстати обратите внимание: типа геометрии "Polyline" не предусмотрено. Из похожего есть "LineString"

**Дубль 3**

Действительно `ObjectManager` более оптимальный вариант для большого количества объектов. И в `Map.geoObjects` каждый `ObjectManager` представлен отдельным объектом, а отображением объектов занимаются уже непосредственно `ObjectManager`'ы. Думаю, решение вашей задачи очень простое: добавить нужное количество `ObjectManager`'ов.

```js
ymaps.ready(function() {
 var map = new ymaps.Map("map", {
   center: [55.76, 37.64], 
   zoom: 7
  });
 var data1 = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
   {"type": "Feature", "id": 1, "geometry": {"type": "Circle", "coordinates": [56.2, 37.3], "radius": 50000}, "properties": {"hintContent": "Текст"}},
   {"type": "Feature", "id": 2, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[56.2, 37.2], [55.3, 37.7], [56.1, 37.9]], []]}, "properties": {"hintContent": "Текст"}},
   {"type": "Feature", "id": 3, "geometry": {"type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[55.7, 37.1], [55.2, 37.6], [56.1, 38.4]]}, "properties": {"hintContent": "Текст"}}
  ]
 };
 var data2 = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
   {"type": "Feature", "id": 1, "geometry": {"type": "Circle", "coordinates": [56.9, 37.3], "radius": 50000}, "properties": {"hintContent": "Текст"}}
  ]
 };
 var om1 = new ymaps.ObjectManager();
 var om2 = new ymaps.ObjectManager();
 om1.add(data1);
 om2.add(data2);
 om1.objects.options.set({
  strokeColor: '#f00',
  strokeWidth: 4,
  fillColor: '#00ff0040'
 });
 om2.objects.options.set({
  strokeColor: '#0f0',
  strokeWidth: 2,
  fillColor: '#0000ff40'
 });
 map.geoObjects.add(om1);
 map.geoObjects.add(om2);
 $('#blue').on('click', function() {
  om1.objects.options.set({
   strokeColor: '#00f'
  });
 })
});
```

```html
<button id="blue">Сделать синим</button>
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 280px"></div>
<script src="https://yastatic.net/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
```

Comment: подобный пример  видел, но в нем объекты добавляются не через objectManager (а это принципиально, потому что объектов очень много), а поштучно.

Comment: Видимо все равно я плохо понял ваш вопрос. Давайте разбираться. Что именно у вас добавляется на карту? Покажите пример  содержимого переменной `data` из строки `objectManager.add(data);` И какова цель разделения на группы?

Comment: дополнил вопрос.., цель разделения на группы - после загрузки данных с сервера присвоить определенной группе определенные цвета отображения на карте После этого все объекты одной группы выглядят одним цветом, при этом сэкономить трафик при загрузке, потому что смысла хранить цвета объектов в базе нет, но пока это по моему единственный вариант (хранить в базе уже подготовленные данные для каждого объекта)

Comment: здорово!, это то что надо!, прошу вас показать код как загрузить gq1 и gq2 в objectManager (у меня не получилось)

Comment: зачем вам это нужно? почему вы хотите добавлять именно в него, а не добавлять GeoQueryResult на карту? и, кстати, как у вас определена переменная objectManager?

Comment: я боюсь того, что при большом количестве загруженных данных у меня просто перестанет всё работать, а objectManager по описанию специально разработан для работы с большим количеством объектов, и отображает только те данные, которые находятся в видимой области, может я конечно и не прав, но вот тут графики говорят сами за себя (График 1, График 2) https://habrahabr.ru/company/yandex/blog/243665/

Comment: objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager();

Comment: Оказывается совсем не здОрово. И я же читал эту статью когда-то :( Но мне не приходилось добавлять больше сотни объектов на карту, а несколько десятков работают вполне сносно. Век живи - век учись... Дополнил ответ еще раз.

Comment: я вам Очень благодарен за вашу помощь и терпение!